# Angular - RoutingLink Not Showing Page Content With No Error Found

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i have an issue using angular routinglink, since the following page didnt showing after i click the link. The URL give me the right path, but its not showing anything, with no error found.

i have already read the documentation from [a link](https://angular.io/guide/router) and some example from stackoverflow

here's the sample of my code

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, enableDebugTools } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './shared/login/login.component';

// Deklarasi Routing
const routingAplikasi : Routes = [
    {path : 'login', component : LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routingAplikasi),
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegistrasiComponent } from './registrasi/registrasi.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavbarComponent, LoginComponent, RegistrasiComponent, FooterComponent],
  exports: [
    NavbarComponent, FooterComponent, LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

navbar.component.html

```
<form class="form-inline">
            <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-primary">Masuk</a>
            <a routerLink="/daftar" class="btn btn-primary">Daftar</a>
</form>
```

app.component.html

```
<navbar></navbar>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
</div>

<footer-bar></footer-bar>
```

i expect the output of "Login Works" that is the value of LoginComponent.

Comment: if you just type the url (localhost:4200/login), does it work? or the issue is only related to routerLink?

Comment: yes, i've been try to manually type the url.. but it doesnt show the LoginComponent value

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for your issue?

Comment: what is it bruh huhu.. sorry, im have not try it yet.

Comment: It's an online vscode + angular project, you can create your code there and share it, then we can fork and debug

Comment: Try adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to `routingAplikasi` (the routes). So your route path would be `{path : 'login', pathMatch: 'full', component : LoginComponent}`

Comment: thanks all, it has been solved, its was my mistake, because im follow the example code of angular 2, that is not match with my project version.. im using angular 8